# Why does std::inlcudes use the less than operator in the condition rather than the equality operator?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this implementation of the algorithm `std::includes` from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
bool includes(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
              InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2)
{
    for (; first2 != last2; ++first1)
    {
        if (first1 == last1 || *first2 < *first1)
            return false;
        if ( !(*first1 < *first2) )
            ++first2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

- It works just fine however I wonder why in the second `if statement`  inside the loop uses less than operator `<` rather than equality operator `==`?
- Here is my similar implementation:

  ```
  template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
  bool including(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
              InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2){

     while (first2 != last2){
        if (first1 == last1 || *first2 < *first1)
           return false;
        if ( *first1 == *first2 )
           ++first2;
        ++first1;
     }
      return true;
  }


  int main(){
     std::vector<int> v{1, 5, 7, 23, 24, 57, 77};
    //  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
      int a[]{7, 24};
      std::cout << including(v.begin(), v.end(), a, a + 2) << '\n'; // 1
      std::cout << std::includes(v.begin(), v.end(), a, a + 2) << '\n'; // 1

  }
  ```
- So I've concluded this:
- The first condition: `*first2 < *first1` -> returns false.
- The second condition: `!(*first1 < *firs2)` -> `*first1 >= *first2`

So `*first1 > *first2` causes the algorithm return `false` and `*first1 >= *first2` causes `firsts2` be incremented so the only condition `first2` gets incremented is when `*first1 == *first2` So why using the less than `<` along with negation operator `!` operators rather than using directly equals operator `==` like in my implementation?

- Is that only for some sort of readability and compatibility sake?
- Is my analysis correct? Thank you!

Comment: Because most of the standard algorithms and standard contains use a less-than comparison for comparisons (and ordering).  So the principle of least surprise applies.  As you note in your question equality can be synthesised from less-than. See also [C++ named requirements: Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is working on a sorted range. You need a `<` relation to sort a range of elements, but not necessarily a `==` relation, hence using `<` poses less restrictions and is more generic.

---

Also consider that most algorithms and containers use `<` rather than `==` to compare elements. See for example [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare requirements, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a).

Two keys in a map are considered equivalent (not equal!) when `!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)`. Most of the time this is the same as `a == b`, but not necessarily.

Comment: I don't think the "most algorithms and containers" argument is strong, but the precondition of being sorted and thus implied existence of less-than relation is a good one.

Comment: @eerorika actually it could be a counter argument, because I'd expect `includes` to check equality not "just" equivalence. Not sure if I should remove that paragraph ....

Answer (score 2):

All of the standard algorithms related to ordering of elements use only the `<` operator, and never the `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, or `!=` operators.

One thing this means is that a class type which should support ordering only needs to define `operator<`, and the others might not be needed.

But another reason is that most of the sort/order algorithms do NOT assume that the objects are "completely ordered", meaning that exactly one of `a<b` or `a==b` or `a>b` is always true. Instead, they assume they have a strict weak ordering, where pairs of elements with `!(a<b) && !(b<a)` true form equivalence classes but are not necessarily equal.

For an example, a simple class for a case-insensitive ASCII string:

```
#include <string>
#include <strings.h>
class ci_string {
public:
    explicit ci_string(const char* s) : m_str(s) {}
    const char* c_str() const { return m_str.c_str(); }

    friend bool operator<(const ci_string& s1, const ci_string& s2)
    { return strcasecmp(s1.c_str(), s2.c_str()) < 0; }
    friend bool operator>(const ci_string& s1, const ci_string& s2)
    { return s2 < s1; }
    friend bool operator==(const ci_string& s1, const ci_string& s2)
    { return s1.m_str == s2.m_str; }
    friend bool operator!=(const ci_string& s1, const ci_string& s2)
    { return !(s1 == s2); }
private:
    std::string m_str;
};
```

(Not suitable for multibyte encodings or non-ASCII letters.)

Now `ci_string("HELLO")`, `ci_string("HeLLo")`, and `ci_string("hello")` are all equivalent but not equal. And for code like:

```
std::vector<ci_string> v1{
    ci_string("alpha"), ci_string("beta"), ci_string("gamma"),
    ci_string("delta"), ci_string("epsilon")};
std::vector<ci_string> v2{ci_string("BETA"), ci_string("Delta")};
bool c = std::includes(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

the implementation using only `<` will return true, but one using `==` would probably return false. (Whether this result really makes sense for "includes" is an interesting question, but that's how it's defined.)